# How to go through Wikipedia articles using arrows?

Tags: links, navigation, hyperlink, page

I am interested in increasing my general knowledge by going through a lot of Wikipedia pages, either by going through pages by subject or by going through pages alphabetically, such as in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:AllPages). I prefer using keyboard shortcuts, as that is way faster than using mouse clicks. But I have no clue in finding out the right shortcuts.

My question consists of smaller questions, each asking which keyboard shortcut is the best to use.

- After hovering my cursor onto a Wikipedia-hyperlink (and underlining it), how can I use the arrows to go to the most adjacent hyperlink (and have that selected/underlined)? (Just like in text documents where pressing down an arrow leads you to the most adjacent letter in the direction you pressed.)
- When an underlined hyperlink is selected, which keyboard shortcut can I use to open that hyperlink in a new tab (and stay on the main page where I'm doing my procedure, instead of going to that new opened tab)?
- When I have opened my Wikipedia tabs (let's say I have opened 40 Wikipedia article tabs in 60 seconds, using the two steps above), how can I use the arrows to go to the most adjacent opened tab (which are of course either left or right from the tab you're on)?

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Vimium Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) or [SurfingKeys Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/surfingkeys/gfbliohnnapiefjpjlpjnehglfpaknnc). By using `f` keystroke you have access to all links at the page using one or two letters on the keyboard.
Combination `Ctrl + keys` allows you open link in new tab

Other keystrokes that may be usefull for You:

- `F`       open a link in a new tab
- `J`, `gT`      go one tab left
- `K`, `gt` go one tab right

Take a look at links to find out more. You can define your own suitable shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you! I have downloaded the Chrome Extensions and will practice and play with it.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, you can click on the address bar or anywhere on the page. Press the tab button. It will highlight the next link on the page. You can tab between links. Click enter to go to the URL of the link. Control+Enter will open the link in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Small question: is there a way to have *control* on the direction the links are tabbed? So, pressing tabs focuses on going the reading direction (downwards and to the right). How can I go upwards and to the left? Arrows do not seem to work.

Comment: Shift+Tab goes to the previous link. Tab goes to the next link.

Comment: You can also press control+tab to go to the next chrome tab. control+shift+tab takes you to the previous chrome tab. control+w closes the tab window

Comment: I will practice and play with these shortcuts. Thank you!